# Обратный итератор для алгоритма и массива

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Можно ли написать обратный итератор для обычного целочисленного массива, не порождая его от какого-либо встроенного класса итераторов, - типа `reverse_iterator`. Да так, чтобы его можно было использовать хотя бы с самым простым алгоритмом `for_each()`. Я написал произвольный класс с единственным полем данных `int*p`, и снабдил его всеми операторами итератора произвольного доступа, - пытаясь замаскировать его под обычный указатель. Но алгоритм его выплёвывает, а компилятор пишет кошмар. Вот код моего обратного итератора:
Окончательный вариант. Извините за исправления.

```
class r_iter{
    int * pi ;
public :
    r_iter():pi(nullptr){}
    r_iter(int *p):pi(p){}
    operator int*()const 
    {
        return (int*)(*this) ;
    }
    r_iter & operator=( int * p)
    {
        (*this).pi = p ;
        return *this ;
    }
    int operator[]( int n )
    {
        int *p_temp = pi  ;
        int v_temp = *(pi + n) ;
        pi = p_temp ;
        *this = pi ;
        return v_temp ;
    }
    int operator*()
    {
        return *((*this).pi) ;
    }
    int operator->()
    {
        return *((*this).pi) ;
    }
    // ИТЕРАЦИЯ.
    r_iter & operator++()
    {
        --pi ;
        return *this ;
    }
    r_iter operator++(int notused)
    {
        r_iter temp = *this ;
        pi-- ;
        return temp ;
    }
    r_iter & operator--()
    {
        ++pi ;
        return *this ;
    }
    r_iter operator--(int nutused)
    {
        r_iter temp = *this ;
        pi++;
        return temp ;
    }
    // КОСВЕННАЯ АДРЕСАЦИЯ.
    r_iter operator+(int n)
    {
        int * temp = pi ;
        r_iter res = pi + n ;
        *this = temp ;
        return res ;
    }
    r_iter operator-(int n)
    {
        int * temp = pi ;
        r_iter res = pi - n ;
        *this = temp ;
        return res ;
    }
    r_iter & operator+=(int n)
    {
        pi += n ;
        *this = pi ;
        return *this ;
    }
    r_iter & operator-=(int n)
    {
        pi -= n ;
        *this = pi ;
        return *this;
    }
    // ВЫЧИТАНИЕ УКАЗАТЕЛЕЙ.
    friend r_iter & operator-
        ( const r_iter & itr_1 , const r_iter & itr_2) 
    {
        return itr_1 - itr_2 ;
    }
    // СРАВНЕНИЯ.
    bool operator==(const r_iter & rit)
    {
        return (*this).pi == rit.pi ;
    }
    bool operator !=(const r_iter & rit)
    {
        return (*this).pi != rit.pi ;
    }
    bool operator<(const r_iter & rit) 
    {
        return (*this).pi < rit.pi ;
    }
    bool operator>(const r_iter & rit)
    {
        return (*this).pi > rit.pi ;
    }
    bool operator<=(const r_iter & rit)
    {
        return (*this).pi <= rit.pi ;
    }
    bool operator>=(const r_iter & rit)
    {
        return (*this).pi >= rit.pi ;
    }
    r_iter & base()
    {
        (*this).pi = pi ;
        return *this ;
    }
} ;
```

Кстати, - знаки БОЛЬШЕ,МЕНЬШЕ,ПЛЮС,МИНУС,и т.д. менял на противоположные. Не помогает. Кстати, - надо ли их менять? И если да, то какие? На самом деле всё ещё хуже. 'for_each()' выплёвывает мой итератор работающий даже в прямом направлении.

Answer (score 1):

**Итераторы.
Инструкции по сотворению.**

Как известно, итераторы являются связующим звеном между контейнерами и алгоритмами.
Алгоритмы, - существа весьма разборчивые и придирчивые. Да, они могут работать даже с обычными массивами. Однако для работы с контейнерными классами, - им необходимы некоторые, -  особо деликатесные продукты, - называемые "итераторами". Причём не всякий такой итераторный продукт они готовы скушать, не ругаясь и не отплёвываясь.

Какими именно свойствами необходимо обладать "настоящему" итератору, - мы с вами и постараемся выяснить.

Итак,  давайте попытаемся написать такой совершенно  настоящий итератор для совершенно настоящего... массива. Ну, зачем, скажите вы, массиву итератор? Ну, хотя бы для того, чтобы сократить длину сигнатуры алгоритма, если имена массива и его размера слишком велики.

```
int Array_what_is_interesting_array[NUMBER_WHAT_IS_BIG_NUMBER]
```

На самом деле, -  и такой простой итератор может быть полезным.

Пусть имеется целочисленный массив:

```
const int NUM =12;
int arr_int[NUM] ={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 };
```

Отобразим содержимое массива при помощи алгоритма `for_each()` и функции отображения для целочисленного типа.

```
const int NUM =12 ;
inline void show_int(int&n){cout << n << ",";}
int main(void)

    {
        int  arr_int[NUM] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 };
        for_each(arr_int,arr_int+NUM,show_int);
    return 0;
    }
```

Если мы теперь попытаемся просто так прилепить к этому массиву итератор в виде класса, - пусть даже и шаблонного, - алгоритмы, как мы знаем, - любят шаблоны, - то у нас ничего не получится.

Для того, чтобы алгоритмы смогли проглотить наш итератор, - да и ещё и облизываться от удовольствия, - нужно всего лишь навсего породить его от базовой структуры `iterator`.

Вот как выглядит эта базовая структура.

```
template<class Cat,class T,class Dist = ptrdiff_t,
            class Pointer = T,class Ref = T&>
struct   iterator  {
    typedef T value_type;           // Тип данных.
    typedef Dist difference_type;       // Разность между указателями, или итераторами.
    typedef Pointer pointer;            // Указатель на дынные.
    typedef Ref reference;          // Ссылка на данные.
    typedef Cat iterator_category;      // Категория итератора
} ;
```

Тип `ptrdiff_t` - это специальный тип, использующийся в некоторых классах для хранения разности между указателями или итераторами. В ваших собственных контейнерах вы вполне можете заменить его типом `size_t`, или даже `int`. Хотя лучше, всё-таки, использовать тип `ptrdiff_t`.

От этой базовой структуры порождены все необходимые нам итераторы, которые подразделяются на следующие категории.

```
struct input_iterator_tag {};           
// Итератор ВВОДА.
struct output_iterator_tag {};      
// Итератор ВЫВОДА.
struct forward_iterator_tag: public input_iterator_tag {};  
// Однонаправленный итератор.
struct bidirectional_iterator_tag: public forward_iterator_tag {};      
// Двунаправленный итератор.
struct random_access_iterator_tag: public bidirectional_iterator_tag {};
// Итератор произвольного доступа.
```

(Г.Шилдт,"Полный справочник по С++",М,изд-4,2014, стр. 679)

Слово `tag`, - здесь означает название категории итератора.

Следует помнить, что понятия ВВОД и ВЫВОД понимаются относительно программы.
То есть, - итератор ВВОДА, - `In put`, - считывает значения элементов из контейнера, - или в нашем случае, - из массива, - в программу.
А итератор ВЫВОДА, - `Out put`, - выводит данные из программы и записывает их в контейнер или массив.

Исходя из вышеизложенного, напишем порождение нашего итератора от общего библиотекоэстиэльного предка.

Назовём его `Iterashka` (Итерашка). Название может быть любое.

```
template<class T>
class Iterashka
        : public iterator
                    // Категория итератора
//< random_access_iterator_tag,
//< bidirectional_iterator_tag,
//< forward_iterator_tag,
< itput_iterator_tag,
T,                  // Тип данных.
int,                    // Тип значения разности между указателями или итераторами
T*,                 // Тип указателя.
T&>                 // Тип ссылки.
{..............};
```

Категории итераторов удобно записать "в столбик", из которого каждый раз следует выбирать какую-то одну категорию. Остальные - следует закомментировать.

Итак, - "шапка" класса-итератора изготовлена. Теперь необходимо наполнить этот класс содержимым.
Единственным полем данных в нашем классе будет указатель на данные. Так как итераторы является внутренним интерфейсом для контейнеров, - в том числе и для массивов, - указатель на данные можно поместить и в открытый доступ.

```
public:
        T * p_iter ;
(.......конструктор По-умолчанию и операторы..........)
```

ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ.
На самом деле, лучше это поле-указатель сделать защищённым, и доступным лишь базовой структуре `iterator`. При необходимости, в классе создаётся специальная функция, возвращающая текущее значение этого поля.

Для того, чтобы убедиться в элементарной работоспособности итератора, - сосредоточимся, в основном, на взаимодействии итератора с алгоритмами. Для этого, - ограничим взаимодействие итератора с внешним миром, всего лишь одним оператором присвоения, - `=`. И отметим для себя, что этот оператор предназначен ТОЛЬКО для инициализации внешних объектов.
ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ.
Вместо оператора присвоения, - ничто не запрещает воспользоваться конструктором инициализации. Хотя это и менее универсальное решение.

Как известно, - алгоритм `for_each()`, - использует самые простые итераторы, - итераторы ВВОДА, - `InPut`.

Для обеспечения работы алгоритма нам понадобятся даже не все операторы, по определению входящие в состав итераторов ВВОДА.

Нам понадобятся:
1.
Один оператор инкремента, - в префиксной форме. Постфиксную форму пока записывать не будем.
2.
Два оператора сравнивания, - `==` и `!=`.
3.
Оператор "преобразования объекта класса в указатель на данные". 
4.
Оператор для "внешнего присвоения".
Вот как это примерно должно выглядеть.

```
template<class T>
class Iterashka
        : public iterator
//< random_access_iterator_tag,
//< bidirectional_iterator_tag,
//< forward_iterator_tag,
< input_iterator_tag,
T,  int, T*, T& >                   
{
public :
    T * p_iter ;
// Конструктор по-умолчанию.
        Iterashka():p_iter(nullptr){}
// Оператор преобразования объекта класса в указатель на данные.
        operator T*() { return this->p_iter ; }
// Внешний оператор присвоения.
        Iterashka & operator=( T * p) { this->p_iter =p ; return *this ;}
// Оператор инкремента.
        Iterashka & operator++() { ++(this->p_iter) ; return *this ;}
// Функции сравнивания.
        bool operator ==(const Iterashka & It) { return this->p_iter == It.p_iter ;}
        bool operator !=(const Iterashka & It) { return this->p_iter != It.p_iter ;}
} ;
```

Проверим работу нашего итератора на примере простого алгоритма `for_each()`. Этот алгоритм применяет функцию, являющуюся его третьим аргументом, - к диапазону, представленному его первым и вторым аргументами.
Итак, проверим наш итератор. Для этого:
1.
Включаем в программу заголовок `<algorithm>`.
2.
Пишем функцию отображения данных. Например, такую:

```
void show_int( int &n){cout << n << ", ";}
```

3.
Объявляем два объекта класса `Iterashka`, и инициализируем их указателями на начало и конец массива.

```
Iterashka<int> i_begin =arr_int;
Iterashka<int> i_end =arr_int+NUM;
```

При этом, важно помнить, что указатель "хвоста" последовательности, - ссылается на элемент, находящийся за последним элементом этой последовательности.

ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ.
Инициализируйте правильно шаблонный тип итератора. Не вздумайте написать что-то типа:

```
Iterashka<arr_int<int>[NUM]> .......и т. д.
```

В таком виде итератор работать не будет. Это касается не только обычных массивов, но ваших собственных рукотворных контейнеров, а так же контейнеров, принадлежащий библиотеке `STL`.
Шаблонный итератор типа такого:

```
Iterashka< vector<int>>.............и т. д.
```

так же работать не будет. Даже не смотря на то, что вы инициализируете его встроенными методами вектора `begin()` или `end()`.

4.
Записываем алгоритм.

```
for_each(i_begin,i_end,show_int) ;
```

Если нет ошибок, то содержимое массива отобразится на мониторе.

Добавим оператор "доступа", -  `operatorT*()`. Он будет работать вместо оператора "преобразования объекта в указатель", и, - соответственно, - чуть быстрее него. Для того, чтобы убедиться в том, что оператор "доступа" действительно заменяет оператор "преобразования...", - закомментируем оператор преобразования.

Итак, наш итератор работает. Первый этап работы завершён.

*************           *************               *************

Есть и более простой, и удобный способ заставить нашего "Итерашку" работать с алгоритмами. 
Для этого, - не нужно порождать наш класс итератор от структуры `iterator`. Достаточно отдельно от объявления класса итератор, - прописать его специализацию в структуре `iterator_traits`.
Вот как выглядит эта структура.

```
template<class Iterator>
struct iterator_traits
{
        typedef Iterator::ptrdiff_t  difference_type;   // Разность между итераторами.
        typedef Iterator::T  value_type;            // Тип данных.   
        typedef Iterator::T* pointer_type;          // Указатель на данные.
        typedef Iterator::T&  reference_type;       // Ссылка на данные.
        typedef Iterator::Cat  category_type;       // Категория итератора.
} ;
```

Прописать необходимо следующее.

```
template<class T>
class Iterashka
{...........} ;

template<class T>
struct iterator_traits<Iterashka<T>>
{
        typedef  int defference_type;
        typedef  T  value_type;
        typedef  T* pointer_type;
        typedef  T&  reference_type;
        typedef  input_iterator_tag;
} ;
```

После того, как для нашего итератора прописана такая специализация, - алгоритмы начинают его любить так же, как если бы он был порождён от базовой структуры `iterator`, даже ещё больше.

У этого способа есть ещё одно преимущество. Он позволяет использовать в качестве итератора... нешаблонный класс.

```
class Iterashka{
public;
        int * p_iter;
(............и так далее...........)
};

template<>      // Спецификация данных пропускается.
iterator_traits<Iterashka>  // Теперь итератор не является шаблонным классом.
{
        typedef int difference_type;
        typedef int value_type;
        typedef int* pointer_type;
        typedef int& reference_type;
        typedef input_iteraror_tag iterator_category;
};
```

ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ.
Если вы работаете с непрерывной последовательной памятью, а сам итератор является, фактически, указателем на данные, то в структуре необходимо прописать только категорию итератора. Остальные её поля можно закомментировать. Однако, если итератор совершает какие-то более сложные действия, - как, например, - итератор в связном списке, - то прописаны должны быть все поля структуры.

Можно создать и такой специальный итератор, который будет инициализировать не только массив, но и любой контейнер с соответствующим целочисленным или символьным типом данных. Для этого, правда, придётся задействовать алгоритм `copy()`. При помощи этого итератора можно так же просто отобразить диапазон целочисленных значений. Правда, для этого функция отображения данных `show_int()` должна принимать аргумент не по ссылке, а по значению.
Вот как это выглядит.

```
class Copyrashka
{
public:
        int value;

        Copyrashka(int &v)value(v){}
        int operator*(){return this->value;}
        Copyrashka & operator++()
        {
            ++(this->value);
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const Copyrashka & Cp)
        {
            return this->value == Cp.value;
        }
        bool operator!=(const Copyrashka & Cp)
        {
            return this->value != Cp.value;
        }
};

template<>
srtuct iterator_traits<Copyrashka>
{ typedef input_iterator_tag iterator_category;};

int const NUM =12;
void show_int(int  n);  // Аргумент принимается по значению.
int main(void)
{
        int a =0, b =0;
        int b_int[NUM];
        a =2; b =14;
        copy(Copyrashka(a),Copyrashka(b),b_int);
        for_each(b_int,b_int+NUM,show_int);

        list<int> ls(25);
        a =2 ; b =28;
        copy(Copyrashka(a),Copyrashka(b),ls.begin());
        for_each(ls.begin(),ls.end(),show_int);
        a =3 ; b =15;
        for_each(Copyrashka(a),Copyrashka(b),show_int);

return 0;
}
void show_int(int  n)       // Аргумент принимается по значению.
{ cout << n << ", ";}
```

Воистину жаль, что числа с плавающей точкой или, например, объекты класса `string` нельзя инкрементировать! :)

*************           *************               *************

Теперь превратим наш обычный итератор... в "реверсный" итератор. Вот и главная причина создания обычного итератора. Реверсный итератор проще изготовить из обычного работающего итератора, чем создавать "с нуля".

Для этого скопируем класс `Iterashka`, и дадим ему новое название. Например, - `Reverashka`, - (Реверашка).
Для превращения такого простого итератора, который у нас получился в "реверсный" итератор, - необходимо проделать всего две вещи:
1.
Изменить способ доступа к данным, хранящимся в итераторе.

```
T & operator*()
{
        T * p_temp = nullptr ;
        p_temp = this->p_iter ;
        ++p_temp ;
    return *p_temp ;
}
```

2.
Заменить знак в операторе "инкремента".

```
Reverashka & operator++(){--(this->p_iter); return *this;}
```

Следует помнить, что начальный реверсный итератор ссылается на элемент, стоящий за последним значащим элементом последовательности. То есть на тот же самый элемент, на который ссылается обычный итератор конца последовательности. В нашем случае, - `I_end`.

А конечный реверсный итератор, - ссылается на первый элемент последовательности. То есть на тот же самый элемент, на который ссылается обычный итератор начала последовательности. В нашем случае, - `i_begin`.

Оператор доступа реверсного итератора всегда ссылается на предыдущий, - с точки зрения обычной нумерации элементов последовательности, - элемент.

Объявим и инициализируем два реверсных итератора и подставим их в алгоритм `for_each()`.

```
Reverashka<int> r_begin =arr_int+NUM;
Reverashka<int> r_end =arr_int;

for_each(r_begin, r_end, show_int );
```

Если нет ошибок, то содержимое массива отобразится на мониторе в обратном порядке.

*************           *************               *************

Проверим работу наших итераторов.

Проверим работу обоих типов итераторов для различных размеров массива. Для этого создадим функцию инициализации неинициализированного массива заданного размера. Эта функция будет иметь одну внешнюю переменную-счётчик, аналогичную счётчикам, используемым в циклах:

```
cnt =0;
void set_int( int n)
{
        n = 0 ;   // Важно не забыть инициализировать переменную.
        n +=cnt ;
        ++cnt ;
}
```

Теперь, - закомментируем массив, объявим его снова, и, инициализируем его при помощи того же самого алгоритма `for_each()`.

```
const int NUM =100;
// int  arr_int[NUM] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
arr_int[NUM];
for_each(i_begin, i_end, set_int);
```

После этого вы можете проверить работу ваших итераторов с любым размером массива, какой только потянет ваш компьютер.

*************           *************               *************

Если все предыдущие действия у вас получились, то в качестве практики разработки итераторов вы можете сделать следующее.

1.
Превратите ваш итератор "ввода", -  теперь он ваш, - в итератор "произвольного доступа".
Для этого, - добавьте в него следующие операторы.
а.
Операторы доступа:

```
operator -> ()
operator [ ] ()
```

б.
Операторы итерации:

```
operator ++ ( int notused )
operator -- ()
operator -- ( int notused)
```

в.
Операторы косвенной адресации:

```
operator + ()
operator - ()
operator += ()
operator  -= ()
```

г.
Оператор разности итераторов. Это позволит исключить функцию "преобразования объекта класса в указатель на данные", - так как она небезопасна.

```
operator - ( const Iterashka & It)
```

д.
Операторы сравнивания.

```
operator > ()
operator < ()
operator >= ()
operator <= ()
```

Ну и, - соответственно, - поменяйте категорию итератора.

ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ.
Вообще-то говоря, алгоритмам, - по большей части, - наплевать на заявленную в вашем итераторе категорию. Главное для них, - это наличие или отсутствие правильно работающих операторов.

То же самое проделайте с реверсным классом.

ЗАМЕЧАНИЯ.
В постфиксных формах, а так же в операторах косвенной адресации, - возвращайте локальный объект класса, - по значению. Не возитесь с указателями на объект класса только ради того, чтобы вернуть разыменованный указатель на объект класса.
Следите за указателями. Они всегда должны ссылаться на конкретный объект, или быть нулевыми.
Не забудьте в реверсном итераторе поменять знак в операторах сравнивания и в операторе разности между итераторами.
Ни в коем случае не инициализируйте тип шаблона итератора самим вектором.
Например так:

```
themplate< class  Vector <T> >
class Iterashka : public iterator< ...>
{ .....  }

Это - глупость.
```

Проверьте работу ваших итераторов с алгоритмами `random_shuffle()` и `sort()`.

2.
Напишите простой контейнер типа вектор и добавьте к нему обычный и реверсный итераторы. Включите в ваш вектор конструктор диапазона. Сделать это легко. Просто добавьте к нему шаблон "итератор":

```
template< class Begin_end_end >
class Vector( Begin_end_end &  start , Begin_end_end &  finish )
{ ........  }
```

Как видите, - обозвать тип, под которым будут вписаны итераторы начала и конца диапазона, - вы можете как угодно.

3.
Напишите двусвязный "незакольцованный" список и проделайте с ним тоже самое.

ЗАМЕЧАНИЯ.
Следите за указателями. Они всегда должны ссылаться на конкретный объект, или быть нулевыми.
Помните, что в списке, - вы сами задаёте направление и способ инкрементирования итератора. Поэтому, - в реверсном итераторе необходимо поменять только операторы инкремента и декремента. А операторы сравнивания и оператор вычитания итераторов следует оставить без изменений.

4.
Напишите двусвязный "закольцованный" список.

ЗАМЕЧАНИЯ.
Вам придётся придумать оператор разности итераторов.
Ещё у вас возникнут проблемы с алгоритмом `random_shuffle()`. Этот алгоритм будет тасовать все элементы, включая и нулевой, - базовый узел. В результате, - один из элементов вашего списка будет потерян.
Решение проблемы может быть таким. Как известно, - итератор хвоста закольцованного списка ссылается на базовый узел. Исходя из вышесказанного, - от проблемы можно избавиться при помощи простого цикла:

```
random_shuffle(begin(), end() );

while( end() != .....значение элемента базового узла .........)
        random_shuffle(begin(), end() );
```

Правда, такое решение не является вполне оптимальным. Оно, конечно, избавляет вас от потери элемента списка, однако создаст дополнительную нагрузку на аппаратные средства.
Очевидно, - именно поэтому, - создатели библиотеки `STL` не снабдили контейнер `list` итератором произвольного доступа, запретив тем самым некоторым алгоритмам с ним работать.

Тем не менее, протестируйте работу вашего списка с алгоритмами `random_shuffle()` и особенно `sort()`. Для алгоритма `sort()`, - итераторы списка слишком громоздки и он не сможет с ними полноценно работать. Тем не менее, добейтесь того, чтобы последовательность хотя бы из восьми или десяти элементов он всё-таки бы отсортировал. Хорошего универсального решения здесь, судя по всему, не существует. Алгоритм `sort()` ведёт себя весьма своеобразно. Зато, такая проверка будет, по крайней мере, означать, что ваш итератор ну хоть как-то "цепляет" этот алгоритм. На моём компьютере он без проблем справляется с 32 элементами.
Протестируйте ваш итератор так же с алгоритмом `stable_sort()`. Он должен отсортировать массив любого размера, с каким справится ваш компьютер.

5.
Протестируйте все ваши итераторные массивы и контейнеры с классом `string`.

На этом у меня всё. Буду рад услышать ваши отзывы.
Желаю удачи.

Comment: Текст почти не читал, но заметил грубые ошибки.

Comment: "От этого базового класса порождены все необходимые нам итераторы, которые подразделяются на следующие категории." -- это неправда. Итератор не обязательно должен быть унаследован от `std::iterator`. Достаточно лишь, чтобы для нашего итератор существовала корректная специализация `std::iterator_traits`. 
"Слово "tag", - означает ящик, точнее - контейнер. Ну, в крайнем случае - массив." -- это вы в каком словаре такое значение нашли? "tag" -- имеет значение "ярлык", "метка"

Comment: Понятие "tag" исправил. Спасибо. Однако, что касается порождения итераторов, то по этому поводу Г. Шилдт пишет так:"Класс iterator является базовым для всех итераторов". Может быть я что-то неправильно понял. Короче, - каким ещё образом можно заставить итератор работать с алгоритмами? Буду рад услышать Ваш ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Держите http://ideone.com/5Ubxac . `CountingIterator` вполне себе работает с алгоритмами, при этом не наследуется от `std::iterator`.

Comment: В любом случае, в ответе много бреда и лишней информации. Например: * "Для того, чтобы алгоритмы смогли проглотить наш итератор ... итератору нужны всего ДВЕ ВЕЩИ. ПЕРВОЕ. Включить в программу заголовок <iterator>. ВТОРОЕ. Породить наш итератор от базового класса iterator." -- ни 1, ни 2 не является необходимым. * "вы вполне можете заменить его (ptrdiff_t) типом size_t, или даже int." -- нет, size_t беззнаковый, int может не хватить. * "Категории итераторов удобно записать "в столбик", из которого каждый раз следует выбирать какую-то одну категорию. Остальные - следует запожолить." --что?

Comment: "Для алгоритма sort(), - итераторы списка слишком громоздки и он не сможет с ними полноценно работать. Тем не менее, добейтесь того, чтобы последовательность хотя бы из восьми или десяти элементов он всё-таки бы отсортировал. Хорошего универсального решения здесь, судя по всему, не существует. Алгоритм sort() ведёт себя весьма своеобразно." -- вот это вообще шедевр.

Comment: Уважаемые господа! Прежде всего, БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО! Благодаря Вам - я узнал много нового. Сделал добавления. Исправил ошибки. Что касается алгоритма sort(), то он вообще не предназначен для использования со связным списком. Тем не менее, в зависимости от того, как Вы напишете в связном списке функцию разности итераторов, - этот алгоритм будет вести себя по разному. Это просто эксперимент. Вообще я писал для таких же как я. Не знаю как для Вас, но для меня подобные очерки иногда просто спасение. Ещё раз большое спасибо за Ваши замечания.